# How can a specify specific bluetooth adapter?

Tags: 12.04, bluetooth

How can I get the bluetooth UI to use a specific bluetooth adapter when more than one is available?

My laptop's built-in bluetooth adapter has glitches. So I bought a USB bluetooth adapter. I'm able to command-line utils to connect a device with the 2nd adapter, but I can't get the UI to use it. :(

**Steps for manual connection:**

```
# Step 1: Find alias for my adapter
sudo hciconfig
# hci1: <stuff> (this is the new one)
# hci0: <stuff> (built-in)

# Step 2: Discover available devices
bt-adapter -a hci1 -d
# <bd mac>

# Step 3: Bind bluetooth device
bt-device -a hci1 -c <bd mac>

# Step 4: Connect audio device
bt-audio -a hci1 -c <bd mac>
```

**Ubuntu release:**

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS
Release:    12.04
Codename:   precise
```

Comment: I might be able to help, edit your question to add the results from `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net` and `lsusb`

Comment: I'm not trying to fix the built-in device. I just want to select the device the UI uses. The devices shouldn't matter, I'd be suspect if they did.

Comment: There are a few different ways to fix it if you post the info

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could manually shut it down with `sudo hciconfig hci0 down` but a udev rule could work also `gksudo gedit  /etc/udev/rules.d/10-local.rules` and enter the following

```
ACTION=="add", KERNEL=="hci0", RUN+="/usr/bin/hciconfig hci0 down"
```

Save, exit and reboot

Comment: In 22.04, I tried adding this udev rule, but both interfaces still came up at boot time.  Solved using <https://askubuntu.com/a/899144/1125384>.