# Disable a single BT adapter

Tags: 14.04, drivers, usb, bluetooth

I have a laptop with 2 BT adapters, one internal (Broadcom BCM2045B; WIFI+BT adapter) and one external (CSR USB BT Dongle). I want to use only the latter because it supports Bluetooth 4.0, unlike the first one.
On Ubuntu 14.04, how can I disable the first one permanently and make the system use the latter (I guess by setting the it to hci0 and the internal to not hci0)?
I'll appreciate the help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can a specify specific bluetooth adapter?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/594843/how-can-a-specify-specific-bluetooth-adapter)

Comment: I'm not sure who's `hci0` at startup. How can I tell?

Comment: Check `hciconfig -a` and look at manufacturer that will be listed

Answer (score 0):

Found the best way to do using this answer (unbinding the usb device): https://stackoverflow.com/a/23033318/3526940