# Deactivate internal bluetooth adapter while leaving usb dongle online

Tags: drivers, usb, sound, bluetooth

I'm having a problem with the BCM43142A0 Bluetooth module. I've already tried this solution: [Bluetooth Broadcom 43142 isn't working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/632336/bluetooth-broadcom-43142-isnt-working).

BT hardware such as headphones can now be connected but keep losing connection (audio stops and resumes out of joint with video). Als othe system keeps freezing. Last entries `/var/log/syslog` are bluetooth-related almost every time.

I have a usb-dongle which should be working but need to disable the internal one (hoping that this will end the crashing).

`lsusb` gives:

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 048d:8386 Integrated Technology Express, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 03eb:8c1d Atmel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 105b:e065 Foxconn International, Inc. BCM43142A0 Bluetooth module
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 5986:0535 Acer, Inc  
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 0a12:0001 Cambridge Silicon Radio, Ltd Bluetooth Dongle (HCI mode)
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 05e3:0608 Genesys Logic, Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

I would like to disable the one from foxconn while leaving the other one (from cambridge silicon radio) active.

I think this isn't possible by editing `/etc/modprope.d/blacklist` because this would deactivate bluetooth altogether.

Answer (score 15):

You can create a udev rule to disable the internal bluetooth

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/udev/rules.d/81-bluetooth-hci.rules
```

Paste the following in

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="105b", ATTRS{idProduct}=="e065", ATTR{authorized}="0"
```

Save, exit text editor and reboot

Comment: Thanks a lot, this helped!

Comment: Thank you for this. Using lsusb I was able to ding my vendor and product IDs. https://www.gaunt.dev/blog/2022/linux-and-bluetooth-dongle/