# Having disabled a BCM43142A0 Bluetooth adapter, how do I remove the proprietary kernel blob?

Tags: drivers, bluetooth, broadcom

I've successfully disabled my laptop's internal Broadcom Bluetooth adapter using [this procedure](https://askubuntu.com/a/899144/1125384).  All is now working fine with my replacement (non-Broadcom) external Bluetooth adapter.  However, I think the now-disabled adapter was probably being driven by a proprietary kernel blob that I installed a long time ago with b43-fwcutter.  Can I safely remove that blob, and if so how, please?

Comment: The b43-fwcutter is just a way to install Broadcom wifi firmware, it shouldn't cause any issues.  Do you want to disable the Broadcom wifi?

Comment: @Jeremy31 Yes, in fact I've already disabled the Broadcom wifi.  Bit hazy on how I did that, possibly by apt removing bcmwl-kernel-source.  The Broadcom Bluetooth was unaffected by that, though.

Comment: b43 firmware has nothing whatever to do with bluetooth.

Comment: AH, OK.  The manpage for b43-fwcutter just says it's for "Broadcom 43xx hardware", it forgets to specify "only the wifi bits".  Nevertheless, I still (probably) find myself with a blob in my kernel from when I was using the wifi adapter, and would still kind of like to remove said blob.

Comment: It is much easier to simply blacklist the module(s). Please run: `lsmod` and paste the result here and give us the link: http://paste.ubuntu.com

Comment: @chili555 Thanks.  That paste site appears to require an Ubuntu One account, and ISTR reading the Ubuntu One Terms of Use a couple of years ago and thinking "no way".  I have bcma and (probably irrelevant) btbcm loaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest that you blacklist *bcma*.

```
sudo -i
echo "blacklist bcma"  >>  /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
modprobe -r bcma
exit
```

Now check:

```
sudo lshw -C network
```

Your Broadcom wireless device should now appear as UNCLAIMED.

**EDIT**: Please try:

```
sudo modprobe -r bcma
sudo modprobe -r cfg80211
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

Reboot.

Comment: It does indeed, thanks.  I'll see later if the UNCLAIMED-ness survives a reboot (blacklisting sometimes seems to be ignored for modules that are loaded as dependencies of another module).

Comment: Oof.  After a reboot, the "UNCLAIMED" has gone away and lsmod reveals bcma is loaded again.  I've checked, and the relevant line is definitely present in /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf.

Comment: Please check again: `lsmod` Are any of these loaded? cfg80211,mac80211,ssb,bcma,cordic or b43?

Comment: Yes: cfg80211 and bcma.

Comment: Please see my edit in a few moments.

Comment: Thanks.  Should I also add cfg80211 to blacklist.conf?

Comment: Do you have another wireless device? USB, perhaps? Does it also depend on cfg80211?

Comment: Ah: when I try to modprobe -r cfg80211, I get a complaint that the module is in use by 88x2bu, which does indeed relate to the chipset in my new USB wifi interface.