# How to disable the bluetooth in the pc but enable bluetooth from a usb?

Tags: usb, bluetooth

Hey so I just started using ubuntu again recently after a while and I have this tiny bluetooth usb stick because my bluetooth at the motherboard is not good.
in windows I just go to device manager than disable the intel bluetooth option and enable the external usb bluetooth one.
How can i do this in ubuntu? its using the inside bluetooth but I want it to disable it.

Sorry if my english is not good i hope you understand me. thanks
i have the latest ubuntu

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Deactivate internal bluetooth adapter while leaving usb dongle online](https://askubuntu.com/questions/898881/deactivate-internal-bluetooth-adapter-while-leaving-usb-dongle-online) just have to modify the udev rule to match you USB ID